# Выгрузка данных из mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

форумчане, прошу о помощи.
Есть таблица в бд, для подключения использую PDO.
Допустим 3 столбца и в ней к примеру 4 записи. (строки)

```
id  userid score
1     12    10
2     15    100
3     10    1000
4     11    10000
```

Эти данные нужно выгрузить в массив, а затем отобразить при помощи к примеру:

```
$id = #что-то;
$userid = #что-то;
$score = #что-то;
echo'<span class="leaderboard_ui">Запись в базе гласит что запись под номером '.$id.' содержит данные о юзере с id: '.$userid.' который успешно набрал '.$score.' очков! </span></br>';
```

Но, как известно несколько, а span всего один, как-же сделать чтобы span создавался самостоятельно для каждой строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// $con - наше подключение, $sql - запрос
foreach($con->query($sql) as $row) {
    sprintf("<span>%d. %d - %d </span><br>", $row['id'], $row['userId'], $score['score']);
}
```